# Asynchronous IO and iteration variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am working with NodeJS and MongoDB and on start I create collections and fill them in if they don't already exist. Right now this is just development , but with backups and things I could end up doing the same thing or something similar in production.

My question is what will happen to the iteration variable(`i`)? Will the callback use the correct value for that iteration? Or will it get some other value further down the list, or perhaps none at all?

```
ldb.createCollection('people', { strict: true }, function(err, col){
    if(err) { console.log('createCollection( people ) ', err); } 
    else { 
        for(var i in people){
            col.insert(people[i], { w: 1 }, function(err, doc){
                people[i]._id = doc._id;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Edit:** This is an object, not an array.

Comment: Since `insert` seems to be asynchronous, then yes `i` will change before the callback is executed. See [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the callback passed into `insert` is called, the value of `i` will not be preserved (it will most likely be the last key in `people`). If you want to preserve `i`, you could give it its own functional scope like this:

```
people.forEach(function(person, i) {
    col.insert(person, { w: 1 }, function(err, doc) {
        person._id = doc._id;
    });
});
```

edit:
Using an anonymous function instead of the forEach method:

```
for(var i in people) {
    function(i) {
        col.insert(people[i], { w: 1 }, function(err, doc){
            people[i]._id = doc._id;
        });
    }(i);
}
```

Comment: What about `(function(var1, var2){ /* do something */ }(this.var1, this.var2);`? Seems like I've seen that used in cases? How would that be done? Would it work? This is an object, not an array, so it doesn't have a foreach function.

Comment: Yes. That would probably be a more precise solution to your problem. I will add an example of that to my answer.

Comment: The only reason I would suggest using a `forEach` call is it's cleaner and avoids common issues associated with `for..in` loops (such as requiring the use of the `hasOwnProperty` method).

Comment: my $0.02: i find it easer to scan when you use a different variable name inside the wrapper than out of it. repeating "i" works and preserves the orig, but it can be confusing...